# Windows Server 2012 R2, multiple Hyper-V Virtual Network Switches for multiple VMs

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, nat, virtual-network

I want to configure something like this:

1. I have one NIC, and have been given 3 IPs by datacenter, on my server which is running WS2012R2, with 10 VMs on hyper-v.
2. Windows Server 2012 R2 (host) one dedicated IP address.
3. Second IP address should be shared by VMs 1-5.
4. Third IP address should be shared by VMs 6-10.

How can I configure this?  Do I need to create TWO additional hyper-v virtual network switches, and some how assign the ip address to this switch and then enable NAT/routing on each of these switches?

What is the best way to configure this, considering performance and reliability.

Comment: Setup one linux/pfsense guest set it up as firewall NAT device for your other guests?  NAT or proxy services as needed.

Comment: Hyper-V is not a firewall nor a NAT device. You only need one virtual switch for all of your VM's. Your firewall/router/nat device should handle the NAT and forwarding for these ip addresses to the VM's.

Comment: It will be much more simple if you can obtain an IP address for each of your VMs. The Hyper-V virtual switch does not have an address of its own and does not route packets.